# Sum a list of options in Scala

Tags: list, scala, sum

How can I sum a list of options `List[Option[Double]]` with the following rules?

- `List(Some(1), ..., Some(n)) --> Some(1 + ... + n)`
- `List(Some(1), ..., Some(n), None) --> None`
- `List(None, ..., None) --> None`

Comment: `val l = list.flatten; if (l.size == list.size) Some(l.sum) else None`

Comment: @Jus12 Another inefficient solution, this requires 2 full traversals of the list, it's not a valid suggestion as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a straight `foldMap` method call, if you're using Cats, you should probably just use that, as it folds over a collection summing the values using a Monoid.

Otherwise, to avoid the traversal of the entire list with a `forall` to check if the entire set of options is defined, you could use a `foldLeft`, and use the fact that you can yield a `None` the first time you find an empty element in the chain.

```
def sumList[ T ] (list: List[Option[T]])(implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Option[T] = {
  list.foldLeft(Option(ev.zero)) { case (acc, el) => 
    el.flatMap(value => acc.map(ac => ev.plus(ac, value)))
  }
}

sumList(List(None, None, Some(5)))
res10: Option[Int] = None

scala> sumList(List(None, None, Some(5F)))
res11: Option[Float] = None

scala> sumList[Double](List(None, None, None))
res13: Option[Double] = None

scala> sumList(List(Some(5), Some(15)))
res14: Option[Int] = Some(20)
```

And to avoid `return` you could simply use recursion(**update**, return is not needed above, but maybe this is easier to follow):

```
@annotation.tailrec
def sumListRec[T](list: List[Option[T]], acc: T)(implicit ev: Numeric[T]): Option[T] = {
  list match {
    // if the list still has elements
    case head :: tail => head match {
      // add the value to the accumulator and keep going
      case Some(value) => sumListRec(tail, ev.plus(acc, value))
      // if you found a None, disregard whatever sum we built so far
      // and just return None
      case None => None
    }
    // If the list is empty, it means we've successfully reached
    // the end of the list, so we just return the sum we built.
    case Nil => Some(acc)
  }
}
```

Watch it in action:

```
scala> sumListRec(List(Some(5D), Some(5D)), 0D)
res5: Option[Double] = Some(10.0)

sumListRec(List(None, None, Some(5D)), 0D)
res2: Option[Double] = None

scala> sumListRec(List(None, None), 0D)
res6: Option[Double] = None
```

Comment: I like the recursive solution. Just used inside the same function without the `acc` and initialized it with `implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero`.

Comment: This solution is way way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @michau That's because yours is inefficient, and will continue the traversal regardless of having encountered a `None`. The devil is in the details. It's also ugly Scala wise, and you revolve to a direct call to `.get`.

Comment: As Donald Knuth said: premature optimization is the root of all evil. There was no indication from OP that his case is one of those 3% that need the most efficient solution, rather than one of those 97% that need the most readable solution.

Comment: @michau This is CompSci 101... nothing premature.

Comment: Anyway, your first solution goes through the whole list, even after encountering `None`.

Comment: Why foldLeft and not fold?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Scalaz this is super easy:

```
targetList.sequence.map(_.suml)
```

Comment: Impressive! I agree with the Knuth proverb, but: how efficient is this?

Comment: @sscarduzio If the list is full of Some instances it'll walk it twice (effectively) to get the result. The first time will produce a List of all the Int values and then it'll walk that list to produce the sum. But if that's slow you're probably better off eliminating the List of Options before anything else.

Answer (score 2):

There is even a simpler way just using fold:

```
val ls = List(Some(2.1d), Some(5.6d), Some(4.3d), Some(1.2))

ls.fold(Option(0d))((rs,x) => for(n <- x; m <- rs) yield {n+m})
```

> => Some(13.2)

```
val ls = List(Some(2.1d),None, Some(5.6d), Some(4.3d), Some(1.2))

ls.fold(Option(0d))((rs,x) => for(n <- x; m <- rs) yield {n+m})
```

> => None

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. **Edit**: changed the code to return immediately after encountering `None`. I admit, this optimisation neither complicates code too much nor impedes readability (as I thought before).

```
def sumOpt(list: List[Option[Double]]): Option[Double] = list.reduce((x,y) => {
  if (x.isEmpty || y.isEmpty) return None
  else Some(x.get + y.get)
})
sumOpt(list)
```

Comment: Do you really need the `return` keyword?

Comment: Yes, because I want to return from `sumOpt`, not from the anonymous function. That allows me to stop immediately after encountering `None`.